# Setting tabstop for bash output

Tags: bash, shell, bashrc

Is it possible to set a tabstop (number of spaces per tab) for the `more` and `less` commands? In vi, I've added this line to `.vimrc`

```
set tabstop=4
```

However when I read through a file with `more` it still uses 8 spaces per tab

```
$ more style.css
div {
        width: 100%;
}
```

Would this be something I could configure in `.bashrc` or a similar file?

Comment: You say tabstop then you say spaces per tab.  Those are two different things.  Which is it you are after?  Tab stops or tab spaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from `man less`:

```
  -xn,... or --tabs=n,...
         Sets tab stops.  If only one n is specified, tab stops are set at 
         multiples of n.  If multiple values separated by commas are specified,
         tab stops are  set  at  those positions, and then continue with the same
         spacing as the last two.  For example, -x9,17 will set tabs at positions
         9, 17, 25, 33, etc.  The default for n is 8.
```

The man page also describes how to set default options for less using setenv or export. Adding `LESS="-x4";export LESS` to your ~/.bashrc should do the trick

Comment: Sorry it took a while to accept this, I was hoping for an answer for `more` since I usually use that out of habit. Since `less` has other benefits anyway, I'll just try to use `less` more :)

Answer (score 4):

I think it's not a property of `bash` (or `zsh`, `csh`... and other shell). It's property of terminal which showed the output.

You can use `expand` command to convert `tab` to number of `spaces`. From `expand` man page:

```
-t, --tabs=NUMBER
              have tabs NUMBER characters apart, not 8
```

So you will do like this:

```
$ cat test.tabs
a        b        c

$ expand -t 4 test.tabs
a    b    c
```